# Django DatetimeField change on update with incorrect value

Tags: mysql, django, datetime

I got a Model like this:

```
class Menu(models.Model):    
 version = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
 local = models.ForeignKey(Local, db_column='id_local')
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True,db_column='created')
 actived = models.DateTimeField(db_column='actived')
 class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'menu'
```

When i created a object of that; all works easy and well. But i got problems updating 'actived'. I use a code like:

```
menu = Menu.objects.get(version=ver, local=local) 
menu.actived = datetime.now()
menu.save()
```

The actived value was correct; when i see it in db (*MySql, with utf-8 charset*) or in template, the value corresponds. But the value of 'menu.created' change to the corresponding of 'menu.created - 1 HOUR'.

I don´t know why; and that´s all the code that i modify.

Comment: It´s not always the same time -1. Each time i try to update the actived time; the created datetime changed (substracting one to the database value, and saved with new value)

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're saying. Sounds like there's some problem translating between the database's format and Python's format, so that the time keeps getting offset. Could be a configuration issue with the database or the adapter, perhaps. It sounds like you have `USE_TZ=False`? Using aware datetimes would probably make this problem go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you have problem with Timezones.Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) documents

And better way is to do this like:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: Why is that better? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) explicitly recommends `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`.

Comment: I tried: created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, db_column='created') / created = models.DateTimeField( db_column='created') / created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True, db_column='created'). Same result; but i think i was mistake explainning myself. Each time you use the function subtracts an hour in database

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i got the solution.

First of all; thanks Kevin Christopher Henry.

In my settings.py i was changed this 3 settings and all works fine.

```
# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = False
```